# Get route url for a http triggered functions in an ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to figure out how to get the route for an HTTP triggered Azure Function within an ARM template.

Thanks to a blog post I managed to find out the listsecret command, but when trying to execute this action via powershell, the output doesn't give me the trigger_url I was expecting. The URL does not comply with the configured route of the function, and shows the default trigger if no route would have been configured.

Any way I can get a hold of the configured route instead since I can't seem to use the trigger_url.

My configured route has got parameters in the path as well, e.g.:

```
{
  "name": "req",
  "type": "httpTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "authLevel": "function",
  "methods": [
    "POST"
  ],
  "route": "method/{userId}/{deviceId}"
}
```

The output of listsecrets is:

`trigger_url: https://functionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/method?code=hostkey`

Is there any other way to extract the host key and route?

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with the API version, but I would suspect that this is not possible as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only way to get the route is by reading the function.json file and parsing that information out, which you can do by using [Kudu's VFS API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API#vfs).

For the keys, I would actually recommend using the [key management APIs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/wiki/Key-management-API) instead of `listSecrets`. As the latter is meant to address a small set of scenarios (primarily to enable some internal integrations) where the key management API more robust API and will continue to work with different secret storage providers (e.g. Azure Storage, which is what is used when slots are enabled and will eventually become the default).